# How can I format a String number without round off?

Tags: java, algorithm, number-formatting

The requirement for me is that user should be able to enter any valid number from a form (the number will be in a string). The application should format the String number with commas in US format without any round-off. This formatted number will be printed in a letter that will be mailed to customers. Most Number formatters will round off the number after a specified amount of precision. This is required in Java but any algorithm in any language will do. I can code that to Java.

Example:

```
Input               Output 
-1.0                -1.0
123                 123
1234                1,234
123456              123,456
-123456             -123,456
-123456.01          -123,456.01
1234.79999999       1,234.79999999
1234567.79999999    1,234,567.79999999
-1234567.79999999   -1,234,567.79999999
```

There is a problem with using DecimalFormat as answered in this question: [Add commas (grouping separator) to number without modifying decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328647/add-commas-grouping-separator-to-number-without-modifying-decimals)

If you define it as below, then you are limited to 2 decimal places. If you increase the number of zeroes in the format pattern, then the decimal places also increase but are fixed. Also, if you give input as 2.1, you will get 2.10. I need 2.1. And if you give an input of 11220.999, then the result will be 11,221.00. I need exactly 11220.999.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add commas (grouping separator) to number without modifying decimals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328647/add-commas-grouping-separator-to-number-without-modifying-decimals)

Comment: @PhamTrung It is a duplicate I believe

Comment: @PhamTrung I need a more "as is" formatting. If you define the format pattern as "#.0000", then 2.1 will give you 2.1000. I need 2.1.

Comment: Manipulate `Strings` (if as regular expressions). Do _not_ convert to `Number` and back.

Comment: If you convert to any floating-point type and back, then you will necessarily lose some digits from the end of long numbers.  E.g., suppose the user entered a number with 1 million digits -- there's just no way all those digits can be represented inside an 8-byte `double`.

Comment: The answer by @dly works the best. While the answer provided by PhamTrung is also very good.

Comment: most of the answers below are good answers. But the one masked as answered is the best one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    String number = "-123456.799999";
    double realnumber = Double.parseDouble(number);
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);  
    System.out.printf("%s", nf.format(realnumber));
    // System.out.println(nf.format(realnumber)); // both work
```

Result `-123,456.799999`

Explanation:
`nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(n);` 
Set this to the highest amount of digits you want to display. All numbers with this number of digits or less after the comma will be displayed like you want them to. Only numbers with *more* digits after the comma will be rounded.

Edit for BIG numbers using String concat

```
String number = "-12342342353356.799999123456789";
int startIndex = number.length()-3;
if(number.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
    startIndex = number.indexOf(".") - 3;
}
int negative = (number.charAt(0) == '-' ? 1 : 0);
for (int i = startIndex; i > 0 + negative; i -= 3) {
    number = number.substring(0, i) + "," + number.substring(i);
}
System.out.println(number);
```

Result: `-12,342,342,353,356.799999123456789`

Comment: on giving an input like -999999999.999999, the result shows -9,999,999,999.999998. Is there any ways that the last 8 can be 9?

Comment: Thats as far as double goes. If you need bigger numbers you need another solution.

Comment: Your way isn't good. How about 123.123456789012? It'll not be displayed to more than 10 decimal digits. The OP wants the value as is, with only commas added "the precision is not defined. It should appear as is; but just with the formatting. If the user gives 2 decimal places, then it should give an output of 2 decimal places. If 5, then 5". Moreover double can't represent correctly most decimal numbers

Comment: fixed for big numbers

Answer (score 2):

What you need is:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(format.format(Double.valueOf("2.10")));
System.out.println(format.format(Double.valueOf("11220.999")));
System.out.println(format.format(Double.valueOf("-1234567.79999999")));
```

Output:

```
2.1
11,220.999
-1,234,567.79999999
-999,999,999.999999
```

For bigger string, you may need to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
BigDecimal de = new BigDecimal("-999999999.99999999999999999999");
System.out.println(format.format(de));
```

Output

```
-999,999,999.99999999999999999999
```

Comment: The last one rounds off :-(

Comment: @RakeshGaria see my updated answer, it will solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
    double number = -999999999.999999;

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
    nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

    System.out.println(nf.format(number));
```

Result:

```
-999,999,999.999999
```

---

another way to deal with very long numbers as String

```
    String number = "999999999999999.9999999999998881928391283";

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(number);

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(format.format(bd.longValue()));

    int index = number.indexOf('.');
    if (index > -1) {
        sb.append(number.substring(index));
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Result:

```
999,999,999,999,999.9999999999998881928391283
```